# Access many UIImageView in a for loop

Tags: objective-c, ios, for-loop, uiimageview

I have 5 UIImageView in a UIView, and I have named the UIImageView as follows:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgPic1;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgPic2;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgPic3;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgPic4;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgPic5;
```

Let's say all UIImageViews are filled with an images, and the user can delete any UIImageView in runtime, I want to know how can I achieve the following scenario?

I want an intelligent loop so if the user delete **imgPic3**, the **imgPic4** image will be moved to **imgPic3**, and **imgPic5** will move to **imgPic4**, and **imgPic5** assign to nil

```
imgPic3.img = imgPic4.img;
imgPic4.img = imgPic5.img;
imgPic5.img = nil;
```

I can hard code the 5 logical scenarios for each UIImageView if got deleted, but I want to do it in an intelligent way so it will work even if I have 100 UIImageViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `NSMutableArray` to contain the 5 `UIImageView` pointers. Then when image view x is removed, do:

```
for (int i = imgViewNumber; i < [myImageViewArray count]-1; i++) {
    [[myImageViewArray objectAtIndex:i] setImage:[[myImageViewArray objectAtIndex:i+1] image]];
}
[[myImageViewArray lastObject] setImage:nil];
```

Edit:
To add your `UIImageView`s to the array:

1. Don't have each one defined as a property nor an iVar - only have a retained property for the array.
2. Use a `for (int i = 0; i < numImageViews; i++)` loop to add all of your image views, and at the same time as calling `addSubview:`, call `[myImageViewArray addObject:imageView]`.
3. Then if you want to set the image for a particular image view, call `[[myImageViewArray objectAtIndex:imageViewNumber] setImage:image]` (bear in mind that for image view 1, imageViewNumber should be 0)

Hope this is now clear

Comment: Thanks @jrtc27 but how can I load NSMutableArray images into the UIImageViews after I finished playing with NSMutableArray?